# How do I get method arguments using Taquito?

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito

When I have a object of type `ContractAbstraction<ContractProvider>`, I can get a key/value map of all the endpoints in the deployed contract like this:

```
const contract: ContractAbstraction<ContractProvider> = client.contract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
const methods = contract.methods;
```

where `client` has type `TezosToolkit` and handles the RPC interaction with a node.

And I can get a list of method (smart contract function) names like this

```
function getObjectMethodNames(obj: any): string[] {
  if (!obj) {
    return [];
  }

  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    .filter((p) => typeof obj[p] === 'function')
    .map((name) => name.toLowerCase());
}
const methodNames: string[] = getObjectMethodNames(contract.methods);
```

But how do I get information about how many arguments each function takes and what type the arguments have? Is that possible using Taquito?

I can see from the block explorer [Better Call Dev](https://better-call.dev/) that this should be possible since they show not only a list of functions for a smart contract but also each function's signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the function signature, not just the function names. This can be done like this.

```
const contract: ContractAbstraction<ContractProvider> = client.contract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
const signatures: string[][] = contract.parameterSchema.ExtractSignatures();
```

`signatures` will then contain an array of an array of strings, where element 0 in each array is the function name, and the rest of the elements are the types from the function signature.

For example, for a basic FA1.2 contract, you would have.

```
signatures = [
["approve", "address", "nat"],
["get_allowance", "address", "address", "contract"],
["get_balance", "address", "contract"],
["get_total_supply", "unit", "contract"],
["transfer", "address", "address", "nat"]]
```

If you want a **dict of the types that each function takes, with the function name as key**, you can get it like this:

```
  const signatures: string[][] = contract.parameterSchema.ExtractSignatures();
  let signatureDict: StringDictionary<string[]> = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < signatures.length; i++) {

    // 0th element is key, the rest are values of the dict
    signatureDict[signatures[i][0]] = signatures[i];
    signatureDict[signatures[i][0]].shift();
  }
```

Comment: But far as I can see, Taquito only supports basic the interpretation of basic types like `nat`, `address`, and `int`. For more complex types like a list of composite types it will just return `list` and not for example `list({"sender": <address>, "amount":<nat>}`. Optimally I would be able to inspect the function signatures as well as I can on the Better Call Dev block explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging around Taquito source code and I cannot find any information about the arguments for each entrypoint.
However, after you created the contract abstraction, you can use the `parameterSchema` property on it to get a JSON representation of the value the contract expects as a parameter:

```
const contract: ContractAbstraction<ContractProvider> = client.contract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
const parameters = contract.parameterSchema;
```

This outputs: `{ "root": { "val": (JSON value) } }`

That being said, I am not sure how this information would be useful as Taquito verifies internally that the provided arguments are correct before emitting a transaction, so you don't have to worry about it :)

Comment: Why it is useful? You can make a pretty sweet frontend for contract interaction if you the function signatures :)

Comment: Have a look at the "Call function" here to see what this can be used for :)
https://myxtzwallet.tokengate.io/

Comment: It's a strongly and dynamically typed interface for making function calls on any deployed smart contract.

Comment: My comment meant "it is not so useful for most dapps" rather than "it is completely useless" :) For a dapp where users are asked to provide raw values that are forwarded to a smart contract, that may be useful, but for the majority of dapps where interactions are button clicks and input of strings/numbers, it is not necessary as Taquito takes care of all the formatting and validating.